# Multiply columns in Dataframe where columns are pd.MultiIndex

Tags: python, pandas

I want to multiply 2 columns (A*B) in a DataFrame where columns are pd.MultiIndex.
I want to perform this multiplication for each DataX (Data1, Data2, ...) column in columns level=0.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data= np.arange(32).reshape(8,4), 
                  columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(iterables = [["Data1","Data2"],["A","B"]]))

    Data1   Data2
    A   B   A   B
0   0   1   2   3
1   4   5   6   7
2   8   9   10  11
3   12  13  14  15
4   16  17  18  19
5   20  21  22  23
6   24  25  26  27
7   28  29  30  31
```

The result of multiplication should be also a DataFrame with columns=pd.MultiIndex (see below).

```
    Data1   Data2   Data1   Data2
    A   B   A   B   A*B     A*B
0   0   1   2   3   0       6
1   4   5   6   7   20      42
2   8   9   10  11  72      110
3   12  13  14  15  156     210
4   16  17  18  19  272     342
5   20  21  22  23  420     506
6   24  25  26  27  600     702
7   28  29  30  31  812     930
```

I managed to perform this multiplication by iterating over columns, level=0,but looking a better way to do it.

```
for _ in df.columns.get_level_values(level=0).unique().tolist()[:]:
    df[(_, "A*B")] = df[(_, "A")] * df[(_, "B")]
```

Any suggestions or hints much appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: Wild guess `df.groupby(level=0, axis=1).mul(axis=1)` probably needs to be combined with `.apply` in some way

Answer (score 4):

Here is another alternative using `df.prod` and `df.join`

```
u = df.prod(axis=1,level=0)
u.columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_product((u.columns,['*'.join(df.columns.levels[1])]))
out = df.join(u)
```

---

```
  Data1     Data2     Data1 Data2
      A   B     A   B   A*B   A*B
0     0   1     2   3     0     6
1     4   5     6   7    20    42
2     8   9    10  11    72   110
3    12  13    14  15   156   210
4    16  17    18  19   272   342
5    20  21    22  23   420   506
6    24  25    26  27   600   702
7    28  29    30  31   812   930
```

Answer (score 4):

Slice out the 'A' and 'B' along the first level of the columns Index. Then you can multiply which will align on the 0th level ('Data1', 'Data2'). We'll then re-create the MultiIndex on the columns and join back

```
df1 = df.xs('A', axis=1, level=1).multiply(df.xs('B', axis=1, level=1))
df1.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df1.columns, ['A*B']])

df = pd.concat([df, df1], axis=1)
```

---

Here are some timings assuming you have 2 groups (Data1, Data2) and your DataFrame just gets longer. Turns out, the simple loop might be the fastest of them all. (I added some sorting and needed to copy them all so the output is the same).

```
import perfplot
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#@Tom
def simple_loop(df):
    for _ in df.columns.get_level_values(level=0).unique().tolist()[:]:
        df[(_, "A*B")] = df[(_, "A")] * df[(_, "B")]
    return df.sort_index(axis=1)

#@Roy2012
def mul_with_stack(df):
    df = df.stack(level=0)
    df["A*B"] = df.A * df.B
    return df.stack().swaplevel().unstack(level=[2,1]).sort_index(axis=1)

#@Alollz
def xs_concat(df):
    df1 = df.xs('A', axis=1, level=1).multiply(df.xs('B', axis=1, level=1))
    df1.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df1.columns, ['A*B']])

    return pd.concat([df, df1], axis=1).sort_index(axis=1)

#@anky
def prod_join(df):
    u = df.prod(axis=1,level=0)
    u.columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_product((u.columns,['*'.join(df.columns.levels[1])]))
    return df.join(u).sort_index(axis=1)


perfplot.show(
    setup=lambda n: pd.DataFrame(data=np.arange(4*n).reshape(n, 4), 
                                 columns =pd.MultiIndex.from_product(iterables=[["Data1", "Data2"], ["A", "B"]])), 
    kernels=[
        lambda df: simple_loop(df.copy()),
        lambda df: mul_with_stack(df.copy()),
        lambda df: xs_concat(df.copy()),
        lambda df: prod_join(df.copy())
    ],
    labels=['simple_loop', 'stack_and_multiply', 'xs_concat', 'prod_join'],
    n_range=[2 ** k for k in range(3, 20)],
    equality_check=np.allclose, 
    xlabel="len(df)"
)
```

[image]

Comment: very intuitive and thanks again for the benchmark :) really appreciated..!! though there is a diff between prod amd mul, I will leave it to OP to decide what they want, but thanks anyways

Comment: @anky and surprisingly the loop the OP proposed seems to be the best :D. And yeah I agree that it can lead to a few differences if there is more data than just those two

Comment: Thanks for the chart. Really cool. If I choose the read it in a very specific way, my solution has the highest results :)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way to do it with `stack` and `unstack`. The advantage: fully vectorized, no loops, no join operations.

```
t = df.stack(level=0)
t["A*B"] = t.A * t.B
t = t.stack().swaplevel().unstack(level=[2,1])
```

The output is:

```
  Data1          Data2         
      A   B  A*B     A   B  A*B
0     0   1    0     2   3    6
1     4   5   20     6   7   42
2     8   9   72    10  11  110
3    12  13  156    14  15  210
4    16  17  272    18  19  342
```

Comment: A join is vectorized (didn't write that it's not). But - I think it's a nontrivial operation ( O(N*M) )

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative here, using [prod](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.prod.html) :

```
df[("Data1", "A*B")] = df.loc(axis=1)["Data1"].prod(axis=1)
df[("Data2", "A*B")] = df.loc(axis=1)["Data2"].prod(axis=1)

df

   Data1    Data2 Data1 Data2
   A    B   A   B  A*B  A*B
0   0   1   2   3   0   6
1   4   5   6   7   20  42
2   8   9   10  11  72  110
3   12  13  14  15  156 210
4   16  17  18  19  272 342
5   20  21  22  23  420 506
6   24  25  26  27  600 702
7   28  29  30  31  812 930
```